# Android Studio 3.4 Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 14

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-manifest

after upgrading Android Studio to version 3.4 my project sync reports an error:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0] C:\Users\pecana\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0b6817155f227f1df719b12aa7dc1519\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 1
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,
    or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 14,
    or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.legacy.v4" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I can by the way build the APK and run the application correctly (but only without instant run active). I tried to add the

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.legacy.v4"/>
```

to the main AndroidManifest.xml but the error still occurs.
Any idea on how to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggested you can also increase your project's minSdk version to 14 or above.

Go to your build.gradle(Module app) file and add the minimum SDK version like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {      
       minSdkVersion 14 or above here
    }      
}
```

Comment: Hello, my app module already include this config :  defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: can you share your entire gradle file?

Comment: Here it is : https://pastebin.com/uEKD16gX and this the "values" ext {
     appCompatVersion = '1.0.0'
     constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.2'
     buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    playserviceGCMVersion ='16.0.0'
    playserviceVersion = "16.0.0"
    playserviceCastVersion = "16.0.3"
    androidxVersion = '1.0.0'
}

Comment: I solved it as suggested! One of my external library ,imported using implementation project("project name") on app build.gradle didn't have a "defaultConfig" section. This was not a problem before updating Android Studio to version 3.4 but now it seems to require it, simply adding it did the magic :-)